# Any curve of constant width is a finite union of arcs of circles?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

Any [curve of constant width](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_of_constant_width) is a finite union of arcs of circles?

Comment: Doesn't the [Constructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_of_constant_width#Constructions) section of the Wikipedia article you linked provide counterexamples?

Answer (score 3):

No; there is no requirement that such a curve be composed of circular arcs.  See [Must a curve of constant width be generated with an odd number of sides?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632266/must-a-curve-of-constant-width-be-generated-with-an-odd-number-of-sides/663099#663099) for more information and examples.